# SQL Server 2005 SSIS Buffer Overflow

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ssis

I'm trying to import a UTF-8 encoded file (not sure if this is relevant) containing 10 columns - the delimiter is þ. I've added a flat file source and set up all the columns as usual and set them to DT_WSTR.

However, it's failing to read in the file as I keep getting the error message below, [advertiser-id] buffer overflow. Advertiser ID is the first column in the file. I've checked the file and all the data is correct, no missing delimiters or columns anywhere. But strangely, it works if there's 1193 rows of data or less, regardless of which rows they are from the file.

Any ideas on why it's work for 1193 but no more? I've tried setting the max rows in the buffer to small numbers and big numbers but still getting the same message.

```
`SSIS package "pck_NetsightV3_Import_Doubleclick.dtsx" starting.
Information: 0x4004300A at Transfer Creative Match Table, DTS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Information: 0x40043006 at Transfer Creative Match Table, DTS.Pipeline: Prepare for Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x40043007 at Transfer Creative Match Table, DTS.Pipeline: Pre-Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x402090DC at Transfer Creative Match Table, Flat File Source [1]: The processing of file "\\man2\systems\Team\datafiles\netsight\doubleclick\latest\doubleclick_matchtables_creative.csv" has started.
Information: 0x4004300C at Transfer Creative Match Table, DTS.Pipeline: Execute phase is beginning.
Error: 0xC020209C at Transfer Creative Match Table, Flat File Source [1]: The column data for column "Advertiser-ID" overflowed the disk I/O buffer.
Error: 0xC0202091 at Transfer Creative Match Table, Flat File Source [1]: An error occurred while skipping data rows.
Error: 0xC0047038 at Transfer Creative Match Table: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "Flat File Source" (1) returned error code 0xC0202091.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
Error: 0xC0047021 at Transfer Creative Match Table: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_THREADFAILED.  Thread "SourceThread0" has exited with error code 0xC0047038.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the thread has exited.
Error: 0xC0047039 at Transfer Creative Match Table: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_THREADCANCELLED.  Thread "WorkThread0" received a shutdown signal and is terminating. The user requested a shutdown, or an error in another thread is causing the pipeline to shutdown.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the thread was cancelled.
Error: 0xC0047021 at Transfer Creative Match Table: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_THREADFAILED.  Thread "WorkThread0" has exited with error code 0xC0047039.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the thread has exited.
Information: 0x40043008 at Transfer Creative Match Table, DTS.Pipeline: Post Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x402090DD at Transfer Creative Match Table, Flat File Source [1]: The processing of file "\\man2\systems\Team\datafiles\netsight\doubleclick\latest\doubleclick_matchtables_creative.csv" has ended.
Information: 0x402090DF at Transfer Creative Match Table, OLE DB Destination [156]: The final commit for the data insertion has started.
Information: 0x402090E0 at Transfer Creative Match Table, OLE DB Destination [156]: The final commit for the data insertion has ended.
Information: 0x40043009 at Transfer Creative Match Table, DTS.Pipeline: Cleanup phase is beginning.
Information: 0x4004300B at Transfer Creative Match Table, DTS.Pipeline: "component "OLE DB Destination" (156)" wrote 0 rows.
Task failed: Transfer Creative Match Table
SSIS package "pck_NetsightV3_Import_Doubleclick.dtsx" finished: Success.
The program '[7916] pck_NetsightV3_Import_Doubleclick.dtsx: DTS' has exited with code 0 (0x0).`
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a a redirect for failed rows? That way you could count out the possibility of there being an invalid character. This error tends to relate to there being a fault with the input file.

Comment: It seems unlikely that there's a defect that is hit at 1193 rows of unicode data. A more likely culprit is a bad line ending (perhaps a row only has CR, CRLF or LF which is inconsistent with the rest of the file). We'd need more information to go on. Also, verify that you are patched up to date. I ran into a nasty bug with 2005 RTM. Different from what you're experiencing but still, SP4 is current for 2005

Comment: Open your Connection Manager for the flat file and take a screen shot of the Advanced tab and update your question with that and at least one sample row of data.

Comment: This is resolved now - had to create a script to encode it to ANSI then it imported fine.